# How long should I wait to drive after taking a painkiller?

Tags: medications, side-effects, drug-metabolism

Recently, I was prescribed hydrocodone. Part of the instructions I was given (on the label, from the physician, and from the pharmacist) included not to drive while taking the medication. However, it wasn't clear (and I didn't ask at the time) *how long* the driving restriction applies.

- The medication label states to take no more than one pill every six hours. **6 hours?**
- [This drugs.com Q&A](http://www.drugs.com/answers/acetaminophen-hydrocodone-long-hydrocodone-stay-655142.html) says it stays in your body 24 hours, with no citation and little explanation. **1 day?**
- Should I trust my own judgment (**when I no longer feel woozy**)? This seems like the least safe option.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there are no direct instructions in regards to this.

> "This drug may make you dizzy or drowsy. Do not drive, use machinery, or do any activity that requires alertness until you are sure you can perform such activities safely." [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/drugs/2/drug-251/hydrocodone-acetaminophen-oral/details)

If you have confidence that you feel alert, and capable of completing a task that requires your full-attention, then it *may* be safe for you to do so. The second option being that, you don't take the medicine when you know that it can favour ill-conditions that *may* pose as an impediment/risk on your personal safety and to those around you. That's not to say that dosing should be seized permanently, just in periods when you know that your alertness is indispensable.

I would recommend that you make sure that you are conditioned to daily functioning on hydrocodone, before you consider driving or operating in a way that may elicit danger.

[This](http://abcnews.go.com/Health/LivingWithPain/story?id=4052173) may add further guidance on the issue